# Plotting a sequence of double arrays, and refreshing the graph after each plot, using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Each iteration at line 97 gives me arrays for x and y coordinates respectively.

```
for step in range(N_OF_DTs):
```

I'd like to plot an iterations result, clear the window, and then plot the next iterations results.

I'm using python 3.

I don't know enough python to display data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
np.random.seed(314159)


N_OF_DTs = 1000
DT = 0.001
DTover6 = DT/6.0
WIDTH = 20
I_EXT = 1.1
WEIGHT = 0.24
grid_u = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH)) 
fired = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))
u = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))
k1 = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))
k2 = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))
k3 = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))
k4 = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))   
spike_data = np.zeros((WIDTH, WIDTH, N_OF_DTs), dtype=object)

def init_grid():
    global grid_u
    grid_u = np.random.rand(WIDTH,WIDTH)   

def clear_fired_grid():
    global fired
    fired = np.zeros((WIDTH,WIDTH))

def step1_grid():
    global grid_u
    u  = grid_u
    k1 = -u + I_EXT
    k2 = -(u + 0.5*k1*DT) + I_EXT
    k3 = -(u + 0.5*k2*DT) + I_EXT
    k4 = -(u + k3*DT) + I_EXT
    grid_u = grid_u + DTover6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 +k4)

def check_fired_grid():
    for i in range(WIDTH-1):
        for j in range(WIDTH-1):
            check_fired_neuron(j,i) 

    global fired    
    spike_data[0,0,step] = fired

def check_fired_neuron(j,i): 
    if grid_u[j,i] > 1:
        grid_u[j,i] = grid_u[j,i] - 1
        global fired
        fired[j,i] = 1
        propagate_to_neighbors(j,i)
        check_fired_neighbors(j,i)     

def check_fired_neighbors(j,i):
    if j > 1:
        check_fired_neuron(j-1,i)
    else:
        check_fired_neuron(WIDTH-1,i)

    if j < WIDTH-1:
        check_fired_neuron(j+1,i)
    else:
        check_fired_neuron(1,i)

    if i > 1:
        check_fired_neuron(j,i-1)
    else:
        check_fired_neuron(j,WIDTH-1)

    if i < WIDTH-1:
        check_fired_neuron(j,i+1)
    else:
        check_fired_neuron(j,1)

def propagate_to_neighbors(j,i):
    if j > 1:
        grid_u[j-1,i] = grid_u[j-1,i] + WEIGHT
    else:
        grid_u[WIDTH-1,i] = grid_u[WIDTH-1,i] + WEIGHT
    if j < WIDTH-1:
        grid_u[j+1,i] = grid_u[j+1,i] + WEIGHT
    else:
        grid_u[1,i]   = grid_u[1,i]   + WEIGHT
    if i > 1:
        grid_u[j,i-1] = grid_u[j,i-1] + WEIGHT
    else:
        grid_u[j,WIDTH-1] = grid_u[j,WIDTH-1] + WEIGHT
    if i < WIDTH-1:
        grid_u[j,i+1] = grid_u[j,i+1] + WEIGHT
    else:
        grid_u[j,1]   = grid_u[j,1] + WEIGHT


init_grid()
plt.figure()

for step in range(N_OF_DTs):
    clear_fired_grid()
    step1_grid()
    check_fired_grid() 
    temp2 = np.nonzero(spike_data[0,0,step])
    if not temp2[0].size == 0:
    print(temp2)
    print('iteration number == '+ str(step) + '\n')
    plt.plot(temp2[0], temp2[1], 'ro')
    plt.draw()
```

And here's the current output.

```
(array([3, 4]), array([17, 17]))
iteration number == 0

(array([12]), array([18]))
iteration number == 7

(array([15, 16]), array([7, 7]))
iteration number == 104

(array([18]), array([7]))
iteration number == 113

(array([ 2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,
        6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
       10]), array([17, 18, 19, 18, 19,  1, 18, 19,  0,  1,  2, 16, 17, 18, 19,  1,  2,
       17, 18, 19,  1,  2, 17, 18, 19, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       16]))
iteration number == 122
```

I expected a 'video' sort of output, because of the iteration, but i got just one 'plot'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAWpG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the figure to be updated, you can introduce a small pause after `plt.draw()`

```
for step in range(N_OF_DTs):
    clear_fired_grid()
    step1_grid()
    check_fired_grid() 
    temp2 = np.nonzero(spike_data[0,0,step])
    if not temp2[0].size == 0:
        print(temp2)
        print('iteration number == '+ str(step) + '\n')
        plt.plot(temp2[0], temp2[1], 'ro')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1) # add a pause so that the events can be drawn on the figure
```

Which will update the figure on each iteration, producing the desired "video" effect